# CodeIgniter: Making thumbs

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I have a problem making thumbs after an image upload. I can upload images perfectly but it doesn't make thumbs for me. I have a map uploads where the original images are stored and a map thumbs in uploads. It's probably a path issue i guess. Thanks

This is my code in my controller.

```
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '6000';
    $config['max_width']  = '3024';
    $config['max_height']  = '3768';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);    
    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    }   
    $datap = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

    $gallery_path = realpath(APPPATH . '../uploads');
    $upload_data = $this->upload->data();

    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = $upload_data['full_path'];
    $config['new_image'] = $gallery_path . '/thumbs';
    $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config['width'] = 75;
    $config['height'] = 50;

    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: none, the original image gets uploaded and i get redirected like it should do.

Comment: What are the permissions of the $gallery_path . '/thumbs' directory? Does the web server have permission to write the thumb file there?

Comment: Also, I don't think realpath(APPPATH); will return the directory separtor, IE '/'. Therefore you will need to use realpath(APPPATH . '/../uploads'); Check if realpath() is returning FALSE to see if the directory you are trying to use exists or not.

Comment: if i do it like '/../uploads' i get /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/famarte/uploads. That seems right. But still no thumbs